# Exercise $2.1.1$ - Differential Topology by Guillemin and Pollack

Tags: differential-topology

If $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $V \subset H^k$ are neighborhoods of $0$, prove that there exists no diffeomorphism of V with U.

Here, $H^k$ is simply the upper half-space.

I tried to solve this problem with the continuity, but it is a dead-end. I have difficulty to solve this problem. Anyone could give me a hint to complete this problem?

Comment: The inverse function theorem should help. Of course, if you are allowed to use algebraic topology, you can actually prove that the two neighborhoods are not even homeomorphic.

Comment: There is an algebraic topology solution using relative homology, similar in  flavor to the proof of the invariance of domain theorem. Are these familiar topics to you?

Comment: "Hk is simply the upper half-space." Open or closed?

Comment: @zhw.: Closed, or else the problem is false. (Also, 0 is not in the open upper half space.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the comments have suggested using algebraic topology.  That sounds horrifying.  Let's be analysts and ignore hard stuff.  The idea is pretty clear.  If $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $H^k$, it's going to have to contain a piece of the boundary.  But there's nowhere for the boundary to map to in $U$.

If $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $H^k$, it contains a neighborhood of the form $D = \{x = (x_1, ..., x_k): |x| < \epsilon, x_k \ge 0\}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  Let $f:U \to V$ be the supposed diffeomorphism.  Pick $x \in U$ so that $f(x) \in D$.

Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, we can write $f(s) = f(x) + Df_x(s-x) + h(s-x)$, where $\frac{|h(s-x)|}{|s -x|} \to 0$ as $s \to x$.  Since $f$ is actually a diffeomorphism, $Df_x$ is actually a linear isomorphism.

At this point, we'd like to force $s$ out of $H^k$.  Choosing a new coordinate system if necessary, we may take $Df_x$ to be the identity map, so really near $x$ we have that

**A brief aside to justify the above:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space of dimension $k$.  Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear isomorphism.  Choose any basis $v_1, ..., v_k$ for $V$.  Let $w_j := T^{-1}(v_j)$.  Then $w_1, ... , w_k$ is also a basis for $V$ (you should check this).

Now let's think of $T:(V, \{w_1, ... , w_k\}) \to (V, \{v_1, ..., v_k\})$.  What does $Tx$ look like for $x \in V$?  Since $T$ has the property that $Tw_j = v_j$ for any $j$, if $x = x_1 w_1 + \dots + x_k w_k$, then we have that $Tx = x_1 v_1 + \dots + x_k v_k$.  This is what I mean by representing $T$ by the identity through a choice of basis.

Going back to the above, we've written $f(s) = f(x) + Df_x(s-x) + h(s-x)$ for $Df_x$ a linear isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$.  Choose a basis $v_1, \dots, v_k$ for $\mathbb{R}^k$ so that $Df_x(v_j) = e_j$, where $e_j$ is the $j$th basis vector.

Let $| \cdot |_{v}$ denote the norm on $\mathbb{R}^k$ with respect to this new basis.  Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent (exercise!).  Choose a constant $c > 0$ so that $ c^{-1} |\cdot| \le | \cdot|_{v} \le c |\cdot|$.

Since $x \in U$ and $U$ is open, choose $\eta > 0$ so that $B_v(x, \eta) \subset U$, where the ball is taken in our new norm (i.e., $B_v(x, \eta) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^k: |x - y|_v < \eta\}$).

Choose $s = x - \frac{\eta}{2} v_k$.  Clearly, $s \in B_v(x, \eta)$.

Shrinking $\eta$ if necessary, we will have that $|h(s-x)| \le \frac{1}{2}|s-x|$ so long as $|s-x| < \eta$ as well.

So, $f(s) = f(x) + Df_x(s-x) + h(s-x) = f(x) + Df_x(x - \frac{\eta}{2}v_k -x) + h(s-x)$

$= f(x) - \frac{\eta}{2}e_k + h(s-x)$.

Now $f(x) \cdot e_k = 0$, by assumption (we chose $x$ specifically so that the $k$th component of $f(x)$ is $0$).  Additionally, the above bound on $h(s-x)$ implies that $h(s-x) \cdot e_k \le \frac{\eta}{4}$.

Together, this shows that $f(s) \cdot e_k = -\frac{\eta}{2} + h(s-x) \cdot e_k \le -\frac{\eta}{4} < 0$, which implies that $f(s) \notin V$; this is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain me in choosing a new coordinate system, how we can get $Df_x$ to be the identity map? Is the map $f$ such that $f(s) = f(x) + Df_x(s-x) + h(s-x)$ the same as $f$ such that $f(s)  = f(x) + (s-x) + h(s-x)$?

Comment: By assumption, $Df_x$ is a linear isomorphism (the derivative of a diffeomorphism is a linear isomorphism).  So $Df_x$ has an invertible matrix representation.  So, through a series of elementary row operations, we may turn the matrix representation of $Df_x$ into the identity matrix.  These elementary row operations correspond to linear isomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^k$.  The image of the coordinate vectors under these isomorphisms produce new coordinates under which the matrix representation for $Df_x$ will be the identity.  Use these coordinates.

Comment: Yes, it's the same $f$.  All I've done to get to the second representation is to use a new coordinate system, under which $Df_x$ is the identity.  One can of course not go through the hassle of changing coordinates and work with $Df_x(s-x)$ directly.

The point is that $Df_x$ is a linear map, so is pretty well-contained.  It can't linearly map a ball to a half-ball.  The correction term ($h$) can only do so much to try and sort that out; you have enough control over $h$ to prevent that from happening.

Comment: I understand that it is a linear algebra concept. However rigorously, I do not understand what changes between the first form $f(s) = f(x) + Df_x(s-x) + h(s-x)$ and the second form $f(s)  = f(x) + (s-x) + h(s-x)$. Do we have the same h in both forms? Is the domain and/or the codomain change of one form to the other? I miss the little flash to make a difference.

Comment: Here is my recommendation to you.  You are studying differential topology right now.  The strength of the subject is that the spaces in question have a structure that allow many problems to be locally reduced to linear algebra questions.  The technique I've described is very powerful (making a useful change of coordinates).  Open up your linear algebra text and remind yourself of the relevant notions of linear maps.  Think very hard about what I've written, and try to convince yourself that it is true.  Fill in every last detail from my description until you're convinced.  The comment...

Comment: ...section is a tad short to elaborate in full detail; but more importantly, if you're not comfortable with linear algebra, you're going to find differential topology (and indeed, a good bit of mathematics in general!) obtuse and difficult to follow.  Everything you learn in mathematics, at the end of the day, will be something you teach yourself.  I don't mean this to be rude, and I'd be happy to elaborate in the chatroom to avoid an extended conversation here if you wish.  But I really feel like you'll benefit more from spending a good few hours working out the details for yourself.

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited my original post substantially to now tie up all the loose ends.  I hope this clears everything up for you.

Comment: '' Let $|⋅|v$ denote the norm on $\mathbb{R}^k$ with respect to this new basis. Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent (exercise!).Choose a constant $c>0$ so that $c^{−1}|⋅|≤|⋅|v≤c|⋅|$.''  I understand the inequality that you introduced. But what do you mean by '' all norms are equivalent '' ?

Comment: Let $V$ be a vector space.  Let $| \cdot |$ and $| \cdot|'$ be two norms on $V$.  We say these norms are equivalent if there exists a constant $c > 0$ so that $c^{-1} |\cdot| \le | \cdot|' \le c | \cdot |$.  If two norms are equivalent, they generate the same topology.

Comment: Could we proceed in the same way without using a coordinate change? I think not, since we did not explicitly know the $Df_x$ map. Do I have reason to believe that?

Answer (score 10):

Let $\ f:U \to V$ be such  a diffeomorphism. Let $x=f^{-1}(0)$. For $h$ near $x$ we have $f(h)=0+Df_x(h-x)+e(h-x)$ where $\frac {e(h-x)}{|h-x|} \to 0$ as $|h-x| \to 0$. As $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $Df_x$ is a linear isomorphism (since $D(f^{-1})_{f(x)}=(Df_x)^{-1}$ by differentiating $ f^{-1}\circ f =I$ using the chain rule).

Let $V=(Df_x)^{-1}(-1,0,0,\dots,0)$, and $h=x+\frac1NV $ with $N$ so that $h\in U$ and $$\frac{|e(\frac1NV)|}{|\frac1NV|}<\frac1{|V|}$$
Now $f(h)=0+(-\frac{1}N,0,0,\dots,0)+e(\frac1NV)$. As $|e(\frac1NV)|<\frac1N$, $f(h)$ is not in $\Bbb H^k$. So no such diffeomorphism could exist.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the horrible algebraic topology proof that there cannot even be any homeomorphism $f : U \to V$.

First, for every open $U' \subset U$ and every $x \in U'$ we have the following calculation of relative homology:
$$H_k(U',U'-x) \approx \mathbb{Z}
$$
To see why, one chooses an open ball $B \subset U'$ such that $x \in B$, and then one has isomorphisms
$$H_k(U',U'-x) \approx H_k(B,B-x) \approx \mathbb{Z}
$$
The first of these two isomorphisms is an application of the excision theorem, the second is one of the basic steps in the calculation of the homology of spheres.

Second, there exists an open $V' \in V$ and $y \in V'$ and such that
$$H_k(V',V'-y) \approx 0
$$
To see why, one chooses $y$ in the boundary of $V$ and then one chooses $V'$ to be a half-ball whose boundary contains $y$. Then one applies the long exact sequence of the homology of a pair, which has the following consecutive terms:
$$H_k(V') \mapsto H_k(V',V'-y) \mapsto H_{k-1}(V'-y)
$$
The first and last terms are zero because $V'$ and $V'-y$ are contractible (here I assume $k \ge 2$, alternatively if $k=1$ use reduced $H_0(V'-y)$ which will be zero). Therefore the middle term is zero by exactness.

Finally, if there existed a homeomorphism $f : U \to V$ then we could choose $y \in V' \subset V$ as above so that $H_k(V',V'-y) \approx 0$, and then we could set $U' = f^{-1}(V')$ and $x = f^{-1}(y)$, and one would obtain $H_k(U',U'-x) \approx \mathbb{Z}$. But, the homeomorphism $f : (U',x) \mapsto (V',y)$ induces an isomorphism 
$$f_* : \mathbb{Z} \approx H_k(U',U'-x) \to H_k(V',V'-y) \approx 0
$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Define the tangent cone $C_p$ at a point $p$ to be the subset of $T_pM$ given by $\gamma'(0)$, where $\gamma: [0,\varepsilon) \to M$ is a smooth curve. At a boundary point $p \in \mathbb H^k$ I claim $C_p$ is the closed upper-half space. It obviously includes that; but on the other hand given $\gamma: [0,\varepsilon) \to \mathbb H^k$, we have $\gamma(t) = \int_0^t \gamma'(s)ds$, so if $\gamma'(0)$ is not in the upper-half space, neither is $\gamma(t)$ for sufficiently small $t$.

Because diffeomorphisms would preserve tangent cones, and the tangent cone of any point on the interior is $T_p M$, there is no desired diffeomorphism.

This argument generalizes to showing that manifolds with various kinds of corners (squares, pyramids of various shapes, etc) are not diffeomorphic to other kinds: you just show there is no linear isomorphism between the tangent spaces that preserves the tangent cones.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

**Argument 1**

Suppose $f$ was a diffeomorphism from $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ to $V \subseteq \mathbb{H}^k$, and that $f(p)=0$. By shrinking $V$ and $U$, we may assume that $V$ is of the form
$$V=\{x\in \mathbb{H}^k\;| \; \| x \|_2<\varepsilon\},$$
for some $\varepsilon>0$. Thus, we may also assume that $U$ is connected, hence path connected (being an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$). Under these assumptions, $f$ must also be a diffeomorphism of $U \setminus \{p\}$ with $V \setminus \{0\}$.

**Claim:**
Any smooth map $\varphi:S^{k-1} \to V\setminus \{0\}$ is smoothly homotopic to a constant map.

**Proof:** Let $x_0=(0,0,\ldots,0,\varepsilon/2)$. Then the map $F:S^{k-1}\times[0,1]\to V\setminus \{0\}$ given by
$$F(s,t)=tx_0+(1-t)\varphi(s)$$ is clearly smooth, has
$F(s,0)=\varphi(s)$ and $ F(s,1)=x_0$ for all $s \in S^{k-1}$, and maps into $V\setminus \{0\}$, since it is a straght line homotopy. $\square$

Low let us show that $U \setminus \{p\}$ does not have this property. Since $U$ (with $p$ included) is an open set, we may find an embedding $\phi$ of $S^{k-1}$ onto
$$K=\{x \in U \; | \;\; \| x-p\|_2=r\}$$
for some $r>0$. Let $\gamma:K\to U\setminus\{p\}$ be the antipodal map of $K$, i.e. $\gamma(q)=p+2(p-q)=3p-2q$. by the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, the mod 2 winding number $W_2(\gamma, p)=1$.

Suppose now $F$ was a smooth homotopy of $\phi$ to a constant map $g:s\to x_0$. We may assume that $x_0 \in K$. Then this would give rise to a smooth homotopy of $\gamma$ with the constant map $\Gamma:K \to U\setminus \{p\}, \Gamma (k)=x_0$. Since the mod 2 winding number is invariant under smooth homotopies, we would get
$$1=W_2(\gamma,p)=W_2(\Gamma,p)=0,$$
a contradiction.

**Argument 2** (although not super rigorous.)

Assume that we have argued from the assumptions that the derivative $df_x$ must be a linear isomorphism for at every $x \in U$. V must contain a segment
$$r_\varepsilon=\{(0,0,\ldots,0,t)\;| \;0\le t\le \varepsilon\}$$
for some $\varepsilon >0$. Consider the preimage $\mathcal{\gamma}$ of $r_\varepsilon$ in $U$. This must be a smooth curve with endpoints $p \ne q$. Assume that $f(p)=0$. Now extend $\gamma$ to a smooth curve $\Gamma$ at $p$ in $U$, such that $\Gamma$ has $p$ as an interior point. We may assume that $\Gamma$ and $\gamma$
is parametrized so that $$\Gamma:[-\delta,\varepsilon]\to U,$$ where $\delta>0$, $\Gamma(-\delta)=r,\Gamma(t)=\gamma(t)$ for $t \in [0,\varepsilon]$. Now attempt to compute
$$d(f\circ \Gamma)_0(t)=df_p \big (t\Gamma'(0) \big )$$
for $t \ne 0$. We may assume that $\Gamma'(0)\ne 0$. Now $f(\Gamma(t)) \in \mathbb{H}^k$ for arbitrary $-\delta<t<0$, so $f(\Gamma)$ must have a cusp at zero. This is only possible if the derivative of $(f\circ \Gamma)'(0)$ is zero or undefined. Since it is defined by assumption, we are forced to conclude (setting $t=1$) that
$$df_p(\Gamma'(0))=0.$$
Since $\Gamma'(0)\ne 0$ by assumption, we get that $df_p$ has a nontrivial kernel, so $df_p$ cannot be a linear isomorphism, a contradiction.